# How to recover from fatal error with profile2?

Tags: users

I deleted a profile type and I got this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTranslation() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/tohbadco/public_html/sites/all/modules/profile2/contrib/profile2_page.module
>   on line 224

I currently cannot access my site as admin. What should I do to regain access?

Comment: Hello and welcome. First, please keep in mind we are not a free support service. We aim to be a knowledge base. So if your case is urgent, you are in a bad place. Second thing, bugreports are explicitly forbidden, see [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so please ask a question in a way that looks like a question. I edited it for you this time. Last but not least, show us you care and try. Have you tried restoring relevant tables from backup, for example?

Comment: Have you tried to use *drush* from the CLI to disable **Profile2**?